# Java Game of life not giving desired output?

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, conways-game-of-life

Im trying to create conway's game of life in Java, but for some reason, the cells are not coming to life and dying as they should? Im wondering if my comparison algorithm is incorrect? Also after asking to run the evolve function several times, it just prints the same thing over and over again....

Project 4:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {

    private static void printGame() {
        for (char[] row : GameOfLife.grid) {
            for (char c : row) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Created a scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to use");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine()); // Takes file name to find file
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        int i = 0;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int col = 0; col < line.length(); col++) {
                    GameOfLife.grid[i][col] = line.charAt(col);
                }
                i++;
                if (i == 25) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }

        // Prints the initial environment
        System.out.println("Initial set: ");
        printGame();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to see the next generation? Y/N?");
            String q = input.nextLine();
            if (q.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                GameOfLife.evolve();
                printGame();
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameOfLife:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GameOfLife {

    static final int m = 25; // number of rows
    static final int n = 75; // number of columns
    static char[][] grid = new char[m][n]; // Creates an empty (no dots or
                                            // X's)grid of rows and columns.

    static int count_neighbors(int i, int j) {
        int nn = 0; // number of neighbors of cell(i,j)

        if (i > 0 && j > 0 && grid[i - 1][j - 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i > 0 && j < 72 && grid[i - 1][j + 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (j < 72 && grid[i][j + 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (j > 0 && i < 22 && grid[i + 1][j - 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i < 22 && grid[i + 1][j] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i < 22 && j < 72 && grid[i + 1][j + 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }

        return nn;
    }

    static void evolve() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 25 - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 75 - 1; j++) {
                int s = count_neighbors(i, j);
                if (s < 2 || s > 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = '.';
                }
                if ((s == 2 || s == 3) && grid[i][j] == 'X') {
                    grid[i][j] = 'X';
                }
                if (s == 3 && grid[i][j] == '.') {
                    grid[i][j] = 'X';
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome back ;) You should know your if-statements don't need semicolons.

Comment: A good rule of thumb btw is to create *and then use* your constant variables defining things like width, numColumns, ftToMeters, etc. Instead of using random unexplained constants throughout your code. For instance, you should replace every 75 in your code with `n` and every 25 with `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I implemented this, I had a condition that checked if the current cell had a value... can't remember the exact rules, but here is my version using the "snapshot" that @janos mentions.

```
static void evolve() {

    char[][] temp = new char[m][n];
    for (int r = 0; r < m; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            int neighbors = count_neighbors(r, c);
            boolean occupied = grid[r][c] == 'X';
            if (occupied && neighbors < 2) {
                temp[r][c] = '.';
            } else if (occupied && neighbors > 3) {
                temp[r][c] = '.';
            } else if (occupied && (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3)) {
                temp[r][c] = 'X';
            } else if (!occupied && neighbors == 3) {
                temp[r][c] = 'X';
            } else {
                temp[r][c] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
    grid = temp.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `evolve`, as you iterate over the cells, you modify the cell content (alive or dead). This affects the counting of neighbors of the next cell. The game cannot work this way. You need to count the neighbors as they were at the start of the evolution phase, and update the cells all at once at the end of the phase.

One way to do that is to take a snapshot (a perfect copy) of the grid at the start of the phase, and use the snapshot for counting only, without updating. Another way is to put the changes to be done in a list (no updates while iterating), and apply the changes at the end of the phase.